# Keycloak adding custom Freemarker page and access it

Tags: routes, frontend, keycloak, freemarker

I have a problem with Keycloak (I am a newbie):

We have Keycloak set up and running, defined a custom theme which is used. When a specific event in the application happens I want the User to be logged out and be redirected to a custom static page in Keycloak which contains an error message.

I tried to create a custom.ftl-file in Keycloak file-structure under opt/keycloak/themes/customTheme/login. Then I tried to logout (logout-method has a redirect parameter) the user and redirect him to this custom.ftl file with its path.

Is this even possible in Keycloak? I must be missing something, I always get the error message that the page does not exist. Can I route to specific .ftl - files?
After googling this stuff I guess it is only possible to customize existing Freemarker-Files that Keycloak is using with its logic but not extend them, add more and route to them?

Appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to implement a custom REST endpoint (see the https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions_rest for details). Within that endpoint you can lookup the `LoginFormsProvider` and call `createForm` method. Pass the name of the ftl file as a parameter. Then simply pass the response from that method back as a response of your REST endpoint.